# Plugin não cria pagina

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou tentando criar pagina ao ativar um plugin, porém, quando tenta acessar, diz que a pagina não foi encontrada, ela até chega sem criada, mas fica com uma tag "agendado" Segue código abaixo:

```
function projetos()
  {

    $post = array(
          'comment_status' => 'open',
          'ping_status' =>  'closed' ,
          'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
          'post_name' => 'Projeto',
          'post_status' => 'publish' ,
          'post_title' => 'Ver Projeto',
          'post_type' => 'page',
    );

    $newvalue = wp_insert_post( $post, false );
    update_option( 'proj-pages', $newvalue );
  }

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'projetos');
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente passar `post_date_gmt` junto. Coisas estranhas acontecem sem esse parâmetro:

```
$time = time();

$post = array(
      'comment_status' => 'open',
      'ping_status' =>  'closed' ,
      'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time),
      'post_date_gmt' => gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time),
      'post_name' => 'Projeto',
      'post_status' => 'publish' ,
      'post_title' => 'Ver Projeto',
      'post_type' => 'page',
);
```